# WPF Customizing ListView ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I'm trying to make my own graphic style of ListView, but I don't understand the source code. Can anybody explain to me the individual parts of the code below?

```
<!-- =========================================================== ListView ============================================================ -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      Focusable="false">
                            <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                                        Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                                CanContentScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" 
                                                CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="Transparent">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Width="1"
                               Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="HeaderBorder"
                            BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource LightBrush}"
                            Padding="2,0,2,0">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderContent"
                                          Margin="0,0,0,1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Margin="0,0,-9,0"
                           Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="HeaderBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="HeaderBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="HeaderContent" Property="Margin" Value="1,1,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Floating">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Canvas Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                            <Rectangle Fill="#60000000"
                                       Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                       Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Border Name="HeaderBorder"
                                BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                                Background="{DynamicResource LightBrush}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:VsListView}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:VsListView}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="{DynamicResource MainCornerRadius}"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                        Background="Red">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I change the visual style of the header part? Which part of the code deals with this issue? 
I've attached a screenshot. I'm insterested in the white rectangle:

[image]

Comment: `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` - have you even read this code?

Comment: Of course I read this code, but any change I made does not be reflect. Even if I delete this part of the code. The white rectangle is still there.

Comment: Well, probably because it's styling for `ScrollViewer`, not a `ListView`... Again, have you even read this code? It's right there, in the first line `TargetType="ScrollViewer"`

Comment: And again, yes, I read this code! But I think you don't read it to the end. You must scroll down. That code is from this website https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms788747(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I know this website. They are not posting a default code for controls there. It's customised to show how it can be done. I have posted an answer that will help you. It's easier to just create blank project and get the default templates yourself. The original code is pretty straight forward, so you shouldn't get lost in in like in the one from the website you reference to (you don't even have to edit it like they show it).

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. So thank you!

Comment: For the next time, if you have your code from any website, posta a link to it in a question. Sorry if I was too harsh to you, but there are way too many people here who just spam questions like "hey, I don't know how to code at all, so can you do it for me, so I can sell it later?"

Comment: Yeah, I understand it. It's ok. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use Blend to get the default styling and `ContentTemplate`, then just edit it to your needs (keep in mind that names of controls used as a template may have a crucial meaning for logic behind a given control, so be careful what you are editing).

If you don't know how to use Blend to get your control's template, here is a simple tutorial described in a [documentation of Telerik controls](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/styles-and-templates/modifying-default-styles) (don't worry, it works the same for all controls). You just need to create copy of a `ListView.ContentTemplate`, paste it to your application and you are good to go (editing).

Comment: Just a tip: on the Objects and Timeline panel when you create a template for control, there probably will be a new hierarchy displayed. It just jumps deeper into the visual tree of the control. Check every position of the new list if it is possible to generate a new template from it. It's quite often that controls are built from controls that have their own styling.